# Cannot change default root location

Tags: centos, nginx, configuration

I have the following configuration file:

```
# /etc/nginx/nginx.conif
# vim: ts=4

user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    # The default server is in conf.d/default.conf
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    server {
        charset utf-8;
        location / {
            root /data/www;
        }
    }
}
```

There are two files in /data/www: hello.txt and index.html. However, when I type just the IP of my server, the default nginx index page is being shown and it outputs "The page you are looking for is not found." after querying "http://IPaddress.gov/hello.txt".

Logs:

> 2014/07/27 21:54:59 [error] 9070#0: *6 open()
>   "/usr/share/nginx/html/hello.txt" failed (2: No such file or
>   directory), client: clientIP, server: _, request: "GET /hello.txt
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "hostIP"

How to fix my problem?

Comment: Look at the rest of your configuration.

Comment: After commenting-out 'include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;' there are no longer problems with "hello.txt", but  the index page is still default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should edit `/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` file, and change default virtual host settings in that file.